# standard or recommended font for vocabulary or gloss terms

Tags: fonts, formatting

I'm writing notes for my students and in the present section, the bulk of the content is defining terms. To help make the notes more practical, I put the technical terms being defined in bold so that it 'pops' out on the page, when skimming.

I'd like to enhance this effect by also changing the font of these terms (so new font + bold), and wondered if there was a standard font that was paired with the default Tex font (I'm using  extarticle). I imagine it would be slightly larger and sans-seriff. N.B. I'm not actually using a glossary, these notes *are* effectively expanded glossaries.

Comment: Why not just use `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}` in addition to `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}`. You could also make it larger but I wouldn't recommend this if you are using the terms inline because it will throw off line spacing etc. I guess one question is: which font are you using for the rest of the document? If you are using the default Computer Modern Roman, I'd stick with the sans variant as they are designed to complement each other. Similarly for Latin Modern Roman and its sans counterpart. A Minimum Working Example would help give a sense of how exactly you are using it and what might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pepper your text with explicit calls to `\textbf` and `\textsf`, you might find it easier to define a new command to mark your keywords.  For example

```
\newcommand{\key}[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily #1}}
```

then you can mark your key words like this: `here is a new \key{term} to remember`.

This way, if you later regret your choice of font, you only have to change it in one place. Moreover, if you later decide you want to add more function (like adding the key words to an index), you only have to modify the `\key` command.

**NB**: Put the `\newcommand` in the preamble, before the `\begin{document}` line. Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily #1}}
\begin{document}
In particular, any associated \key{supporting element} necessitates that urgent
consideration be applied to possible bidirectional logical relationship
approaches.  Conversely, any associated supporting element recognizes other
systems' importance and the necessity for possible bidirectional logical
relationship approaches.  However, a \key{service-oriented paradigm} is further
compounded when taking into account the evolution of specifications over a
given time period.  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that's an awesome solution! Thanks for taking the time to put it together, much appreciated!