# Semantic indications in LaTeX

Tags: macros

I'd like to include in my LaTeX code some form of indication that certain words are keywords, or that a phrase is a quote, or that another phrase is an example, etc. Where can I find a list of inbuilt semantic indications like these?

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example of what you want to achieve, i.e. a screenshot and a MWE?

Comment: Like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163472/standard-or-recommended-font-for-vocabulary-or-gloss-terms

Comment: Next time please provide an example of what you want. For instance, you could write, "I want the following code...`<code>`...to have the following output...`<output>`."


This way I can clearly see that you require your keywords to be "in the text" and the keywords list generated. I'd be able to tell: weather you want the list to be itemized or listed in paragraph form (keyword1, keyword2, etc), weather you want the keywords to be listed in the body or margin of the document, weather you want them to be listed alphabetically or in the order they appear in the document, etc.

Comment: You can define your own environments to do this: `\newenvironment{toy}[0]{}{}`. then use the environment: `\begin{toy}teddy bear\end{toy}`. Of course this environment doesn't change the style but you can add that if you want to.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example. I just thought it was one of the selling points of LaTeX to just indicate semantics in the document and let it take care of the rest; so I assumed it was enough to just ask a short question. I didn't have anything particular in mind, was just wondering about inbuilt semantic indicators.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many inbuilt semantic macros like that, even though LaTeX premieres dividing semantics from typography. Sometimes you instead define your own command in the preamble, like

```
\newcommand\movie[1]{\textit{#1}}
```

for writing movie titles in italics (especially when you might change your mind about how to render that kind of element later). Or you use a package for handling a special kind of element.

Maybe the kind of keywords you mean (indicated in a special way when introduced) is a job for a package like [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries/). Maybe the kind of examples you mean are like numbered examples in linguistics? There are several packages that do these. I don't think you will find that list, and are better off asking about particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\begin{quote}` and `\end{quote}` for quotations.

For keywords, use the `index` package. Use `^[aut]{yourkeyword}` to identify a keyword. add the example's preamble to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{index}

\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{Name Index}
\newindex{not}{ndx}{nnd}{List of Notation}    
\shortindexingon
\proofmodetrue    
\def\aindex{\index*[aut]}

\begin{document}

Lorem ^[aut]{ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

^[aut]{consectetur} adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae orci ante. Maecenas ^[aut]{viverra}.

interdum molestie dapibus tincidunt, dignissim sit amet risus. ^[aut]{Quisque}.

\end{document}
```

This prints:

[image]

The keywords will appear in the right margin.

Comment: By keywords I mean keywords in the text, not a collection of keywords. So every time I introduce a new keyword I somehow highlight it.

Comment: See my most recent edit.